# can a trading destination city ever get any yields?

Tags: civilization-6

When trying to create trade routes, it looks like I can select a city which changes the yields that get added for the city the trader starts in. But no matter what I pick, the section that shows what the other city gets remains empty.

What do I have to do to generate benefits for both cities in a trade route?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, only the city sending the route gets any benefits. Currently, the only exception is when Cleopatra receives an international trade route.